# Finding Controls in an Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, controls, updatepanel

I have seen a few threads on this.  if I have a control in an update panel when the page loads, I can easily get it with the following code:

```
    Label lbls = (Label)upPreview.FindControl(lbl.ID);
    lbls.Text = lbl.ID;
```

What I cannot do is the following on two different buttons with two different update panels

Button 1:

```
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "something";
    lbl.ID = "something";
    upPreview.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Button 2

```
    Label lbls = (Label)upPreview.FindControl(lbl.ID);
    lbls.Text = lbl.ID;
    upForm.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lbls);
```

essentially I am creating a label and putting it in one update panel, then on the second button click I am moving it to another update panel.  every time I try this, it says:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: child

I have  also tried ControlCollection cbb = upPreview.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls;

same error.  any ideas?

Comment: Did the answer below solve this for you?  If so, please mark the question as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Label lbl` is getting lost during the partial postback when the `Button`s are clicked.  You can use the ViewState to preserve it during postbacks.

Add a single `Label` above your Page_Load and instantiate it to null.

```
protected Label lbl = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) // First load or reload of the page
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "something";
        lbl.ID = "something";
        upPreview.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);        
    }
    else
    {
        // Reinitialize the lbl to what is stored in the view state
        if (ViewState["Label"] != null)
            lbl = (Label)ViewState["Label"];
        else
            lbl = null;
    }
}
```

Then in your Button_Click events:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save the lbl in the ViewState before proceeding.
    ViewState["Label"] = lbl;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lbl != null)
    {
        // Retreive the lbl from the view state and add it to the other update panel
        upForm.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);        
    }
    else
    {
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "Error: the label was null in the ViewState.";
    }
}
```

This way you keep track of it during post backs.